# Detect first init with OLE Server

Tags: c++, file, stack, atl, detect

I write COM DLL in C++ ATL Project. 
I add simple "log stack" (write call method in file) . 
I want clean this file when start new session (how can I detect load library?)

Comment: [`DllMain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks